# Cannot fix grub after running boot repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue, boot-repair, refind

Any help is appreciated. I've been trying to fix this for a couple days now.

Trying to dual boot win8 and ubuntu on an HP envy(15-j1063cl). Whenever I boot my computer I get the "grub rescue" screen. I can boot to either ubuntu or windows 8 by booting the right .efi file from the boot options menu.

I've run boot repair multiple times, but I still can't get past this screen. I would like to use rEFInd, and I've tried installing that as well.

Output of boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7942689/

Comment: You don't say what happened with your rEFInd installation, just that you tried installing it. Please elaborate about the way in which it's not working for you.

Comment: I was hoping you'd show up here :). I installed it and I can access it if I use the "boot from efi" file option on boot. The problem is that I can't get rid of the grub rescue screen. Each time I boot the computer I have to use the boot from efi option.

Comment: In Linux, use `efibootmgr -o` to change the boot order. For instance, `sudo efibootmgr -o 5,0`. If things haven't changed since you posted your Boot Repair output, that should set rEFInd first and GRUB second. Type `sudo efibootmgr` alone to see a list of boot options.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for that comment, that is immensely helpful. I have since wiped my system and reinstalled windows, I haven't installed linux yet but this comment should seems like it should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I only had to launch my current config in order to launch the operating system (GRUB was OK but it couldn't read it's config).

The method I used was:

> set root=(hd<‏tab>

Now you should see the list of possible drives and partitions

Just select the desired one.

Now type:

> configfile=/path/to/file

In my PC it was `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but it may differ on your machine.

After that bust type `boot` and you sould see the correct config.

Now that your OS is up and running just reinstall grub as root on the desired drive and run `update-grub` as root as well.

Update if you need further assistance.

Comment: Hmm I got past the configfile part. But when I typed "boot" I get "unknown command `boot`.

Comment: What grub version? (It says so when the system loads)

Answer (score 0):

Super GRUB2 Disk helps you to boot into most any Operating System (OS) even if you cannot boot into it by normal means.
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/